# Zeppelin unable to start IPython kernel

Tags: ipython, apache-zeppelin

For quite some time I've been facing an issue with Zeppelin which seem to be unable to launch IPython. I followed this [guide](https://www.zepl.com/viewer/notebooks/bm90ZTovL3pqZmZkdS84YjZmZTAzYmE4ZDc0ODg1OTQ0YWM5MDcwYjYyNzQ0Mi9ub3RlLmpzb24) and this [one](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/python.html). Pyspark interpreter is correctly set with the right python path and IPython activated by default. However, when I try to run any of the examples in the guides such as:

```
%ipyspark
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c'], 'count':[12,24,18]})
z.show(df)
```

I get the following error from the logs which doesn't tell much:

```
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:08,653] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[setAdditionalPythonPath]:103) - setAdditionalPythonPath: /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/interpreter/lib/python
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:08,654] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[open]:135) - Python Exec: python3
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:09,189] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[checkIPythonPrerequisite]:195) - IPython prerequisite is meet
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:09,191] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[open]:146) - Launching IPython Kernel at port: 39753
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:09,191] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[open]:147) - Launching JVM Gateway at port: 36511
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:09,402] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[setupIPythonEnv]:315) - PYTHONPATH:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/interpreter/lib/python:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client//python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client//python/:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client//python:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client//python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:09,743] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[launchIPythonKernel]:293) - Wait for IPython Kernel to be started
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:09,844] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[launchIPythonKernel]:293) - Wait for IPython Kernel to be started
WARN [2018-11-30 15:17:09,926] ({Exec Default Executor} IPythonInterpreter.java[onProcessFailed]:394) - Exception happens in Python Process
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.access$200(DefaultExecutor.java:48)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor$1.run(DefaultExecutor.java:200)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:09,944] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[launchIPythonKernel]:293) - Wait for IPython Kernel to be started
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:10,044] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[launchIPythonKernel]:293) - Wait for IPython Kernel to be started
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:39,465] ({pool-3-thread-2} IPythonInterpreter.java[launchIPythonKernel]:293) - Wait for IPython Kernel to be started
WARN [2018-11-30 15:17:39,466] ({pool-3-thread-2} PySparkInterpreter.java[open]:134) - Fail to open IPySparkInterpreter
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to open IPythonInterpreter
    at org.apache.zeppelin.python.IPythonInterpreter.open(IPythonInterpreter.java:157)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.IPySparkInterpreter.open(IPySparkInterpreter.java:66)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter.open(PySparkInterpreter.java:129)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:617)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Fail to launch IPython Kernel in 30 seconds
    at org.apache.zeppelin.python.IPythonInterpreter.launchIPythonKernel(IPythonInterpreter.java:297)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.python.IPythonInterpreter.open(IPythonInterpreter.java:154)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.IPySparkInterpreter.open(IPySparkInterpreter.java:66)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:617)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:39,466] ({pool-3-thread-2} PySparkInterpreter.java[open]:140) - IPython is not available, use the native PySparkInterpreter   
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:39,533] ({pool-3-thread-2} PySparkInterpreter.java[createPythonScript]:118) - File /tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-5362368451576072994.py created
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:39,534] ({pool-3-thread-2} Py4JUtils.java[createGatewayServer]:44) - Launching GatewayServer at 127.0.0.1:34508
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:39,565] ({pool-3-thread-2} PySparkInterpreter.java[createGatewayServerAndStartScript]:265) - pythonExec: python3
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:39,567] ({pool-3-thread-2} PySparkInterpreter.java[setupPySparkEnv]:236) - PYTHONPATH: /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/interpreter/lib/python:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client//python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client//python/:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client//python:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client//python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip
INFO [2018-11-30 15:17:41,953] ({pool-3-thread-2} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:115) - Job 20181129-172919_2135817500 finished by scheduler interpreter_131607019
```

I'm using HDP3.0.1 which comes with Zeppelin 0.8.0. All the nodes have python 3.7.1 installed with the latest version of jupyter and grpcio. From Zeppelin notebook I checked ipython and python version:

```
%pyspark
import sys
import IPython
print(IPython.__version__)
print(sys.version)
```

> 7.2.0
>
> 3.7.1 (default, Nov 29 2018, 17:37:37)

I can start IPython from any node without a problem and Zeppelin can correctly get IPython's version. I tried to find if there are other logs than Zeppelin reporting the error but couldn't find anything.

Any idea of what could be preventing the launch of IPython kernel from Zeppelin?

Comment: did you find the solution? I am running into same issue

Comment: I'm still having the same issue even after changing the python interpreter to anaconda

Answer (score 2):

`pip install --upgrade setuptools pip`

or potentially

`pip install --upgrade ipython`

there are a few other quick things to try here [github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/270](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/270)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too running zeppelin-0.9.0-preview2. In my case, the cause was that zeppelin did not recognize conda installed packages in `pip-freeze`.
For instance, I installed `jupyter-client` using `conda` so `pip freeze` looked like this:

```
➜ pip freeze | grep jupyter-client
jupyter-client @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyter_client_1616770841739/work
```

Notice jupyter-client does not follow the `package==version` format. The solution is to remove the conda installed version of jupyter & install it with pip.

```
➜ conda uninstall jupyter
➜ pip install jupyter
➜ pip freeze | grep jupyter-client
jupyter-client==6.1.12
```

It seems zeppelin should support [both cases](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-jupyter-interpreter/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/jupyter/JupyterKernelInterpreter.java#L176-L184) soon. (If it does not already).

Remember too, that zeppelin-0.9.0 does not support [Python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754720/apache-zeppelin-issues-python-errors) yet.

Answer (score 0):

I did recently run in a similar issue with Apache Zeppelin 0.10.0 and Apache Zeppelin 0.10.1.

The reason (in my case) was that the newest versions installed with `pip install jupyter` will install `jupyter_client==7.4.4`. This is however not recognized by Apache Zeppelin 0.10.0 which looks for the older name of the package (jupyter-client instead of jupyter_client).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74217783/apache-zeppelin-0-10-1-ipython-not-starting-jupyter-client-is-not-installed/74958390#74958390) for more details and a workaround.