# Apache Zeppelin Issues - Python Errors

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

I have an issue with Apache Zeppelin.

When I run a new python notebook and try to execute a command like `import dask`
it results in the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/1599314081091-0/zeppelin_python.py", line 162, in <module>
    code = compile(mod, '<stdin>', 'exec')
TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module.
```

This looks like a setup issue, but I'm not sure where to configure.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error with zeppelin-0.9.0-preview2. It seems Zeppelin is not compatible with python 3.8. Downgrading python to 3.7 fixed the issue. This the issue reported in CPython https://bugs.python.org/issue35894. Looks like we have to wait for Zeppelin to add a fix by checking the python version.

Comment: Also if you plan to use %ipython or %ipyspark interpreters you will have to reinstall ipython, jupyterlab, protobuf and grpcio using pip. Zeppeling cannot detect the versions for those libraries since they come as in place installs in the default Anacond distribution.

This issue tracks the procgress of this bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-5009