# Apache Zeppelin 0.10.1 IPython not starting : jupyter-client is not installed

Tags: ipython, apache-zeppelin

I have setup Apache Zeppelin 0.10.0 following https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.10.0/quickstart/install.html on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

I have a running  vanilla python interpreter setup.
Python is from a conda virtual environment which was installed with:

```
sudo /opt/conda/bin/conda create --prefix /opt/conda/envs/python3 python=3.9
```

The `zeppelin.python` property points to `/opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/python3`.

I am now trying to setup the recommended IPython interpreter.

According https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.10.0/interpreter/python.html#ipython-interpreter-pythonipython-recommended I installed the following packages in my conda environment:

```
sudo /opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/pip install jupyter
sudo /opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/pip install grpcio
sudo /opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/pip install protobuf
```

However, when I invoke the IPython interpreter in Zeppelin I get this error:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Fail to open JupyterKernelInterpreter:
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: Kernel prerequisite is not meet: jupyter-client is not installed, installed packages:
anyio==3.6.2
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
asttokens==2.0.8
attrs==22.1.0
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
bleach==5.0.1
certifi @ file:///croot/certifi_1665076670883/work/certifi
cffi==1.15.1
debugpy==1.6.3
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
entrypoints==0.4
executing==1.1.1
fastjsonschema==2.16.2
grpcio==1.50.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==5.0.0
ipykernel==6.16.2
ipython==8.5.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==8.0.2
jedi==0.18.1
Jinja2==3.1.2
jsonschema==4.16.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-console==6.4.4
jupyter-server==1.21.0
jupyter_client==7.4.4
jupyter_core==4.11.2
jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
mistune==2.0.4
nbclassic==0.4.5
nbclient==0.7.0
nbconvert==7.2.2
nbformat==5.7.0
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
notebook==6.5.1
notebook_shim==0.2.0
packaging==21.3
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
prometheus-client==0.15.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.31
protobuf==4.21.9
psutil==5.9.3
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pycparser==2.21
Pygments==2.13.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyrsistent==0.18.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pyzmq==24.0.1
qtconsole==5.3.2
QtPy==2.2.1
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
stack-data==0.5.1
terminado==0.17.0
tinycss2==1.2.1
tornado==6.2
traitlets==5.5.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.4.1
widgetsnbextension==4.0.3
zipp==3.10.0
```

I tried as well the same procedure with python version 3.7 without any success (same error resulted).

I do not understand the error message, as it seems to me that `jupyter-client` is installed.

Any hint to what could be the reason for this error is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the answer of Chao Wang, I found the issue [ZEPPELIN-5810](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-5810) which noted that the package name `jupyter-client` has been changed to `jupyter_client` in newer versions. The issue was addressed and implemented in the source code on [Sep 12, 2022](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/commit/23f3acf2086d78630dbc3d18016cb7e40c390ef2).

The currently latest Apache Zeppelin binary version [0.10.1](https://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html) is from Feb 29, 2022 and will not contain the fix.

I used the following workaround to setup my `conda` environment for python:

1. Create the virtual environment:

```
sudo /opt/conda/bin/conda create --prefix /opt/conda/envs/python3 python=3.7.10
```

2. Add the following python packages to it (in this order):

```
sudo /opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/pip install matplotlib==3.4.3
sudo /opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/pip install jupyter-client==6.1.12
sudo /opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/pip install grpcio==1.38.1
sudo /opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/pip install protobuf==3.16.0
sudo /opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/pip install ipython==7.26.0
sudo /opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/pip install ipykernel==6.2.0
sudo /opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/pip install ipython-genutils==0.2.0
```

3. Make sure that the `zeppelin.python` property points to `/opt/conda/envs/python3/bin/python3`.
4. Restart your python interpreter binding.

Answer (score 0):

```
Kernel prerequisite is not meet: jupyter-client is not installed 
jupyter_client==7.4.4
```

Maybe it's the difference between underscore(_) and dash(-)?

When I run `pip freeze | grep jupyter-client` I got nothing.

Instead, got `jupyter_client==7.4.8` for running `pip freeze | grep jupyter_client`

Comment: I get  `jupyter_client==7.4.4` for running `pip freeze | grep jupyter_client`. I noted the difference in underscore and dash between the error message I get and the actual installed packages and added to my puzzling about the source of the reported error from apache-zeppelin,